# how to end email using Rails and js and html button?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

Im new to using rails , and i am trying to figure out a solution to sending an email using an html button, javascript function and rails.

HTML and JS code:

```
<%= form_tag root_path, class: "send-email" do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Click to Send Email", style: "margin: 10px; padding: 10px" %>
<% end %>

<script>
document.querySelector(".send-email").onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  fetch(e.target.action, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "X-CSRF-Token": document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
      window.open('/mail', '_blank')
    } else {
      console.error(response)
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

ContactMailer.rb

```
class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer
    def contact 
        mail(to: 'abdelmoulabilel2000@gmail.com', subject:'testing for fly')
    end
end
```

ContactMailerPreview.rb

```
# Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/contact_mailer
class ContactMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview

    def contact 
        ContactMailer.contact()
    end
end
```

contact.html.erb

```
<h1>Hello this is for testing the email function</h1>
```

And i couldn't figure out how to connect everything together.

Comment: You are missing a controller action. Right now you are making a post request to `root_path` (we don't know where this is). You need to change `root_path` to a path that will reach a controller action that will send the email. Learn More [Here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

Comment: may i ask for how the code of the controller should be ?

Comment: I would recommend just reading through the documentation the [calling the mailer](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#calling-the-mailer) section explains all of this.